# Can "msauth://broker" invoke Intune Company portal app? -iOS

Tags: ios, azure, intune, authenticator

I have usecase to fetch login cache from Microsoft Intune Company Portal App.
 My app already has Azure Ad Sdk integrated. However after looking inside the code, I am wondering Azure ad sdk works only with Authenticator App rather than any other.
As the callback fails and no token is fetched.

Can anyone help me on this. How to invoke a token from Company Portal App. As this is issue only with iOS and working perfectly with Android.

Note: Keychain Id is also mentioned for '**adalcache**'